# Combine SQL statements as columns, not as rows

Tags: sql

First Query:

```
SELECT OPENING.COMP_CODE, COMPANY.COMP_NAME, OPENING.QUAL_CODE, QUALIFICATION.QUAL_DESCRIPTION
FROM OPENING
LEFT JOIN COMPANY ON OPENING.COMP_CODE = COMPANY.COMP_CODE
LEFT JOIN QUALIFICATION ON OPENING.QUAL_CODE = QUALIFICATION.QUAL_CODE
```

Second Query:

```
SELECT EDUCATION.CAND_NUM, CANDIDATE.CAND_LNAME, EDUCATION.QUAL_CODE, QUALIFICATION.QUAL_DESCRIPTION
FROM EDUCATION
LEFT JOIN CANDIDATE ON EDUCATION.CAND_NUM = CANDIDATE.CAND_NUM
LEFT JOIN QUALIFICATION ON EDUCATION.QUAL_CODE = QUALIFICATION.QUAL_CODE
```

I tried using `<Query1> UNION ALL <Query2>` but it combines the results as rows. I want to combine the results as columns (side by side)

Comment: how did you combine these queries? did you try `union all`?

Comment: HEY WHEN I DO UNION ALL IT GIVES ME EVERYTHING IN ONE COLUMN WHEREAS I WANT IT ALL IN ONE ROW.

Comment: Please mention the error you receive while you combining the query with union all. Apparently, the issue may come when the column data type or length is different in both selected result.

Comment: FULL OUTER JOIN the queries.

Comment: SELECT OPENING.COMP_CODE, COMPANY.COMP_NAME, OPENING.QUAL_CODE, QUALIFICATION.QUAL_DESCRIPTION
FROM OPENING
LEFT JOIN COMPANY ON OPENING.COMP_CODE = COMPANY.COMP_CODE
LEFT JOIN QUALIFICATION ON OPENING.QUAL_CODE = QUALIFICATION.QUAL_CODE
UNION
SELECT EDUCATION.CAND_NUM AS `ID`, CANDIDATE.CAND_LNAME, EDUCATION.QUAL_CODE, QUALIFICATION.QUAL_DESCRIPTION
FROM EDUCATION
LEFT JOIN CANDIDATE ON EDUCATION.CAND_NUM = CANDIDATE.CAND_NUM
LEFT JOIN QUALIFICATION ON EDUCATION.QUAL_CODE = QUALIFICATION.QUAL_CODE

Comment: THIS ABOVE CODE GIVES ME ALL VALUES IN ONE COLUMN WHEREAS I WANT MY SECOND SELECT COLUMN ON THE SIDE OF FIRST SELECT LASTS COLUMN

Comment: Why are you shouting?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to bring all the result in one row, UNION ALL / UNION wont work. Use cross apply instead. Such as,

```
SELECT A.* ,B.*
FROM 
(
SELECT
OPENING.COMP_CODE, COMPANY.COMP_NAME, OPENING.QUAL_CODE, QUALIFICATION.QUAL_DESCRIPTION
FROM OPENING
LEFT JOIN COMPANY ON OPENING.COMP_CODE = COMPANY.COMP_CODE
LEFT JOIN QUALIFICATION ON OPENING.QUAL_CODE = QUALIFICATION.QUAL_CODE
) AS A
CROSS APPLY
(
SELECT EDUCATION.CAND_NUM, CANDIDATE.CAND_LNAME, EDUCATION.QUAL_CODE, QUALIFICATION.QUAL_DESCRIPTION
FROM EDUCATION
LEFT JOIN CANDIDATE ON EDUCATION.CAND_NUM = CANDIDATE.CAND_NUM
LEFT JOIN QUALIFICATION ON EDUCATION.QUAL_CODE = QUALIFICATION.QUAL_CODE 
) AS B
```